# A WrapPanel in which selection divides the panel to show a detail view?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

- Scrolling is horizontal
- Touch-driven.
- Items flow down, then into the next column
- Touching an item would scroll the panel to a set point so the detail view would always be in the same spot.
- The next column over would "break off" and animate to the right, to reveal a details pane in the context of the selected item.
- Touching any visible item (in a different column) would "close" the revealed detail, then animate the new selected item to the left static point and again cut the next column away to reveal the detail. Touching any visible item in the same column would just do a fade-out-in animation.

Here are some simple mocks:

[image]

[image]

90% of this is simple to me, but the process to create a wrap panel which can "separate" itself to reveal an item is eluding me in a big way.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Great Idea! I think Infragistics has something like that

Comment: Thanks @HighCore. Downloading Infragistic's trial to see which control you might be referring to.

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions is :

You can separate buttons inside wrap panel(**which is inside grid**) by changing margin of some of them (of course you need to change size of window as well if you want to keep buttons size and avoid moving them to next line).

For example if you have 4 columns and three rows of buttons named button 1,2,3 etc...
when button from first column is clicked buttons 2,6,10 getting :

```
  new thickness(space,0,0,0);
```

This moves all the buttons on the right by value of variable space;

And then

```
  window.width += space;
```

And then textBox which is children of the grid is to locate in suitable place with width space.

On undo

```
      new thickness(0,0,0,0);

      window.width -= space;
```

It worked for me well but i am curious for other solutions.

Comment: Interesting, however I'm not sure if you're saying I should change my window chrome width or not. In my case, that is not a viable option.

Comment: Yea, by window size i meant size of wrap panel and grid (window in some cases), nonentheless this is simple although at some point quite naive way to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

This sounded like a fun task, so I decided to implement something along the lines of what you wanted. I thought I could share it so you can improve it or use it to your liking. First of, this task is beyond my skills of implementing in *only* XAML. I'm not saying it can't be done, just that it's a tad difficult. Instead, I implemented my own Panel type (called `GapPanel`). This might sound even worse, but there's a few nice things about it nonetheless, like the possibility of implementing `RoutedEvent`s to respond to in XAML for animations.

So, here's the load of code. First the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="SlidingWrapPanel.SecondAttempt"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SlidingWrapPanel"
        Title="Wrapped items with details pane" Height="250" Width="600">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="ItemButtonTemplate">
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            To="#999999" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            To="#3e3e3e" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" Background="#3e3e3e" BorderBrush="#222" BorderThickness="1">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="0" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="ItemGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3e3e3e"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ItemButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource ItemButtonTemplate}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="DetailsGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3e3e3e"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="160"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-160" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="DetailsTextStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe WP Light"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15"/>
        </Style>
        <Storyboard x:Key="ExpandColumnAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="GapWidth" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsPanel"
                             From="0" To="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DetailsPanel}" Duration="0:0:0.75">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="DetailsPanel">
                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding GapX, ElementName=ItemsPanel}"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="CollapseColumnAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="GapWidth" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsPanel"
                             To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <QuinticEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="DetailsPanel">
                <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="-160"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="DetailsPanel" Style="{StaticResource DetailsGridStyle}">
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DetailsTextStyle}">
                        <Run Text="Details" FontSize="18"/>
                        <LineBreak />
                        <Run Text="Some text"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <local:GapPanel x:Name="ItemsPanel">
            <local:GapPanel.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:GapPanel.ColumnChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ExpandColumnAnimation}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:GapPanel.CloseGap">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource CollapseColumnAnimation}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </local:GapPanel.Triggers>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource ItemGridStyle}">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ItemButtonStyle}" Content="Item 1" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource ItemGridStyle}">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ItemButtonStyle}" Content="Item 2" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource ItemGridStyle}">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ItemButtonStyle}" Content="Item 3" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource ItemGridStyle}">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ItemButtonStyle}" Content="Item 4"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource ItemGridStyle}">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ItemButtonStyle}" Content="Item 5"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource ItemGridStyle}">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ItemButtonStyle}" Content="Item 6"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource ItemGridStyle}">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ItemButtonStyle}" Content="Item 7"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource ItemGridStyle}">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ItemButtonStyle}" Content="Item 8"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource ItemGridStyle}">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ItemButtonStyle}" Content="Item 9"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource ItemGridStyle}">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ItemButtonStyle}" Content="Item 10"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource ItemGridStyle}">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ItemButtonStyle}" Content="Item 11"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Style="{StaticResource ItemGridStyle}">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource ItemButtonStyle}" Content="Item 12"/>
            </Grid>
        </local:GapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the (abomination) of a panel..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace SlidingWrapPanel {
    public class GapPanel : Panel, INotifyPropertyChanged {
        private readonly IDictionary<UIElement, int> columns;
        private readonly IDictionary<int, double> gapCoordinates;
        private object opened;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty GapColumnProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GapColumn", typeof(int), typeof(GapPanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, columnChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty GapWidthProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("GapWidth", typeof(double), typeof(GapPanel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(double), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        public static readonly RoutedEvent ColumnChangedEvent;
        public static readonly RoutedEvent CloseGapEvent;

        static GapPanel() {
            ColumnChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("ColumnChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEvent), typeof(GapPanel));
            CloseGapEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("CloseGap", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEvent), typeof(GapPanel));
        }

        public GapPanel() {
            columns = new Dictionary<UIElement, int>();
            gapCoordinates = new Dictionary<int, double>();
            GapWidth = 0;
            GapColumn = -1;
        }

        public int GapColumn {
            get { return (int)GetValue(GapColumnProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GapColumnProperty, value); }
        }

        public double GapWidth {
            get { return (double)GetValue(GapWidthProperty); }
            set { SetValue(GapWidthProperty, value); }
        }

        public double GapX {
            get {
                double value;
                gapCoordinates.TryGetValue(GapColumn, out value);
                return value;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public event RoutedEventHandler ColumnChanged {
            add { AddHandler(ColumnChangedEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(ColumnChangedEvent, value); }
        }

        public event RoutedEventHandler CloseGap {
            add { AddHandler(CloseGapEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(CloseGapEvent, value); }
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize) {
            Point location = new Point();
            double position = 0;
            double columnWidth = 0;
            int col = 0;
            foreach (UIElement child in Children) {
                columnWidth = Math.Max(columnWidth, child.DesiredSize.Width);
                position += child.DesiredSize.Height;
                if (position > finalSize.Height && columnWidth > 0) {
                    location.X += columnWidth;
                    if (col == GapColumn) {
                        location.X += GapWidth;
                    }
                    ++col;
                    columnWidth = 0;
                    position = child.DesiredSize.Height;
                    location.Y = 0;
                }
                columns[child] = col;
                child.Arrange(new Rect(location, child.DesiredSize));

                location.Y = position;
            }

            return finalSize;
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) {
            double width = 0, height = 0;
            double position = 0;
            double columnWidth = 0;
            int col = 0;
            foreach (UIElement child in Children) {
                child.Measure(availableSize);

                columnWidth = Math.Max(columnWidth, child.DesiredSize.Width);
                position += child.DesiredSize.Height;
                if (position > availableSize.Height && columnWidth > 0) {
                    width += columnWidth;
                    ++col;
                    columnWidth = child.DesiredSize.Width;
                    position = child.DesiredSize.Height;
                    height = Math.Max(height, child.DesiredSize.Height);
                }
                gapCoordinates[col] = width + columnWidth;
            }

            return new Size(width + GapWidth, height);
        }

        protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved) {
            base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(visualAdded, visualRemoved);
            UIElement element = visualAdded as UIElement;
            if (element != null) {
                element.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += expandAtVisual;
            }
            element = visualRemoved as UIElement;
            if (element != null) {
                element.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= expandAtVisual;
            }
        }

        private void expandAtVisual(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
            // find element column
            int column = columns[(UIElement)sender];
            GapWidth = 0;
            GapColumn = column;
            if (opened == sender) {
                RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(CloseGapEvent, this));
            }
            opened = sender;
        }

        private void onPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private static void columnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
            ((GapPanel)d).onPropertyChanged("GapX");
            ((GapPanel)d).RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ColumnChangedEvent, d));
        }
    }
}
```

Leave a comment if there's anything you feel I need to explain.

Also, I can't help promoting the book "WPF4 Unleashed" by Adam Nathan. Much if not everything I managed to do above is explained in great detail in this book, so it's a great resource for anyone wanting to learn more about WPF.

Comment: There are some good ideas in here that I might be able to utilize.  I think it could be improved by implementing an "`ItemDetailTemplate`" instead of how the DetailsPanel is currently implemented. DataContext could be easily inherited and it would allow for cleaner XAML.  And for what it's worth, I don't see anything wrong with leaning heavy on C# - it makes the XAML much more portable in the end.

Comment: @Erode: Yes, I agree. I also see a possibility of adding RoutedEvents for `OpeningGap`, `OpenedGap` as well as `ClosingGap` and `ClosedGap`, instead of the current two. The idea of an ItemDetailTemplate is really good, that would probably make it a more "suitable" component, as well as cleaning up in XAML as you noted.